# Allowable depreciation for rental property with varying personal usage

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property, cost-basis, depreciation

I have a rental property (in the United States; Washington D.C.) that has not strictly been used 100% for business purposes over time. At various times I have occupied different portions of the property, or have also used it for 100% rental. In the years I used a portion of the property, I declared depreciation according to the percentage of business use (what I believe was the "allowed" depreciation). Now, I'm hearing that "allowable" depreciation is different and should be applied to the full value of the home every year, not the business portion of the home, and that prior years depreciation must be the "allowable" not the "allowed" depreciation.

### My Questions:

1. Did I do depreciation correctly in the years I used a portion of the property?
2. Is "allowable" truly based on the full value of the home, regardless of my percentage of business/personal usage?
3. When I sell the property, is my basis adjusted based on the "allowable" depreciation (if "allowable" is based on the full value of the property) or based on my "allowed" (which I've based on the business usage portion of the value)?
4. Am I completely confused and misunderstanding everything here??

Comment: can you specify the country? It helps when asking tax questions.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Thank you for reviewing and for posting your comment. I've updated to indicate it is in the United States (Washington DC).